# Bind a DataGrid using WPF with MVVm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel

I know this type of questions has been asked a lot of times. But I am trying to achieve this without using InotifyProperty or anything else. I just want plain code for displaying data from a Model. 
For this, I am trying to bind a Datagrid using the following methodology.
I have a Model:

```
public class PrimaryModel
{
    private int _id;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _userName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set { _userName = value; }
    }

    private string _password;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { _password = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _createdDateTime;

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime
    {
        get { return _createdDateTime; }
        set { _createdDateTime = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _lastLoginDateTime;

    public DateTime LastLoginDateTime
    {
        get { return _lastLoginDateTime; }
        set { _lastLoginDateTime = value; }
    }

    private bool _isActive;

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set { _isActive = value; }
    }
}
```

A ViewModel:

```
public class PrimaryViewModel 
{
    private ObservableCollection<PrimaryModel> _UsersList;

    public PrimaryViewModel()
    {
        _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<PrimaryModel>
        {
            new PrimaryModel { ID=1,UserName="Raghava",Password="Something",CreatedDateTime=DateTime.Now,LastLoginDateTime=DateTime.Now,IsActive=true }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PrimaryModel> Users
    {
        get { return _UsersList; }
        set { _UsersList = value; }
    }
}
```

And a XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="usersData" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=_UsersList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I bind the DataGrid to display basic ID and Username through the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public class PrimaryViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PrimaryModel> Users //Allways private set - to not destroy the Binding! Use Clear instead of reintializing !!!
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public PrimaryViewModel()
        {
            Users = new ObservableCollection<PrimaryModel>
            {
                new PrimaryModel { ID=1,UserName="Raghava",Password="Something",CreatedDateTime=DateTime.Now,LastLoginDateTime=DateTime.Now,IsActive=true }
            };
        }
    }
```

u mainly set the `ItemSource` wrong...

```
        <DataGrid Name="usersData" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And because u don't want to update your stuff with `INotifiyPropertyChanged` - set all `Setter` to private, because they fields in your DataGrid do not update currently.

Also why are you wrapping all your Fields in Properties with nothing else !?!

Comment: I am learning WPF with MVVM pattern and do not have much knowledge on the subject. So, basically, I am just trying to populate a datagrid with some data. I tried updating my code as per your suggestions, but am still unable to view an output.

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer: You need to set the DataContext of your View as well. Have you done that?

Comment: What MightyBadaboom said ... Go to MainWindow.xaml.cs    -  then to the constructor     `public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new PrimaryViewModel();
        }`

Comment: I tried adding this.DataContext = new PrimaryViewModel(); but it is not recognizing PrimaryViewModel.

Comment: That's the name of your view model class, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Even so I was unable to use it. Should I refer it like: using Sample4.ViewModel;  ? I have downloaded some projects where they have referred their ViewModels without declaring it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Post your ViewModel Namespace pls

Comment: Just create a new class in your WPF application project, call it PrimaryViewModel and copy the code from your question into it. Then you could refer to my answer.

Comment: I have gone through a project code like this:using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DataGridSample
{
    public class RecordInfo :ViewModelBase
    {
Where the ViewModel is not referred at all, but they were still able to use the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Change your binding in the XAMl code like this `ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Users}"`. You can't bind to a private field; you have to use a public property.

You need to set the `DataContext` of your View as well. Have you done that?

But MVVM and binding without `INotifyProperyChanged` is a bad choice. Your View won't update when your ViewModel is getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of your view model.

You could either to do this in the code-behind of the view:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PrimaryViewModel();
    }
}
```

...or in the XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:PrimaryViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="usersData" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=_UsersList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```